# Getting an anchor element's absolute URL with jQuery

Tags: jquery, url, anchor, absolute-path

Given an anchor element (with something like `$("a:first")`), how do you get the absolute URL that the anchor points to?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you're using jQuery 1.6+, you can use `.prop()`:

```
$("a:first").prop("href")
```

Prior to 1.6, you can access the `href` property directly on the DOM element:

```
$("a:first")[0].href;
```

Comment: Haha, I know, I was just waiting for the 5 min timeout to expire.

Comment: Just to clarify, it's not entirely obvious, but the above *does* turn out to return the absolute, not the page-relative href.  I didn't really believe it until I tried it.  I guess that's the difference between prop() and attr() in this case.

Answer (score 1):

to get the URL attached you can do something like...

`var url = $("a:first").attr('href');` this will give you the URL but doesnt guarantee absolute or relative.

To find the absolute URL you can further check

`if(!url.startsWith("http")) { url = "http://www.mysite.com" + url}`

Comment: `startsWith` is definitely not a native `String` method. Perhaps that is an extension from some library you typically use?

Comment: I agree with you. And yes it wanted to reflect the idea. We could have also used .indexOf()!=-1 instead...

Answer (score 0):

*Without* jQuery, you can leverage vanilla JavaScript:

[`HTMLAnchorElement: toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement/toString) returns a string containing the whole ("*absolute*") URL:

```js
const anchorElement = document.createElement('a');
anchorElement.href = '/help';

console.log("anchorElement object     :", anchorElement);
console.log("anchorElement outerHTML  :", anchorElement.outerHTML);
console.log("anchorElement toString() :", anchorElement.toString());
```

In this example, the `anchorElement` uses the [origin-relative URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#linking_to_relative_urls) `/help` for its `href` attribute:

```
<a href="/help"></a>
```

`anchorElement.toString()` returns the absolute URL:

```
https://stacksnippets.net/help
```

Note: `https://stacksnippets.net/` is the domain serving the code snippet, which *this* page (*stackoverflow.com*) embeds as an `iframe`.

Answer (score -2):

var x = "http://lol.com/" + $("a:first").prop('href');

that should work unless it's an external url :)

Comment: why? :-s. if the <a> is relative it would add to the first url.

Comment: `$("a:first")` returns a jQuery object containing elements matching the selector you passed to jQuery. Adding a string to that result set won't give you anything useful.