# How to use window.location to highlight the active menu item?

Tags: jquery, html, pathname

I'm using following code of `JQuery` to add a `class name` to the active menu item according to the `URL` of the menu item:

```
var aurl = window.location.pathname;
$('.menu li a[href="'+aurl+'"]').parent('li').addClass('active');
```

The problem isn't in the code itself but it's in `window.location.pathname`.

It works when i set the `URL` as the following `HTML` code:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href='/'>home</a></li>
  <li><a href='/page1'>page 1</a></li>
  <li><a href='/page%202'>page 2</li>
</ul>
```

But it doesn't work when i set the `URL` as the following `HTML` code:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href='http://myhost.com'>home</a></li>
  <li><a href='http://myhost.com/page1'>page 1</a></li>
  <li><a href='/page 2'>page 2</a></li>
  <li><a href='http://myhost.com/page 3'>page 3</a></li>
  <li><a href='http://myhost.com/page%204'>page 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

I need something instead `window.location.pathname` that can identify all these cases together.

Thank you

**Update #1:**

I have used 2 variables for the `URL` like this:

```
var aurl = window.location;
var burl = window.location.pathname;
$('.menu li a[href="'+aurl+'"],.menu li a[href="'+burl+'"]').parent('li').addClass('active');
```

It worked with all types but i still can't define the `URL` with `space` i have to replace it with `%20` like:

```
<li><a href='/page 2'>page 2</li>
```

to be:

```
<li><a href='/page%202'>page 2</li>
```

Comment: try dump in console.log window.location object. It can tell you more info

Comment: I have already tried it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to identify both relative and absolute urls, and you want to be sure they match exactly, you will have to get the absolute url of each link and match that. As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171657/getting-an-anchor-elements-absolute-url-with-jquery), the absolute url is found in the `href` *property*, independent of the type of url in the *attribute*.

There is no special selector for properties (that I know of), so you could do something like this:

```
var aurl = window.location.href; // Get the absolute url
$('.menu li a').filter(function() { 
    return $(this).prop('href') === aurl;
}).parent('li').addClass('active');
```

Comment: that's so impressive. It works perfectly with all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
window.location.href
```

instead of Pathname

Answer (score 0):

If you want to identify both relative and absolute urls, I don't think there will be a single `window.location` component that will match both. Have a look at the [jQuery selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) page. Depending on your site structure, perhaps you could use the "Attribute ends with" selector `[name$="value"]`:

```
var aurl = window.location.pathname;
$('.menu li a[href$="'+aurl+'"]').parent('li').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to add active class to li tag if the browser url is equal to that li>a child href 
if this is what you want then here a simple solution :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href='http://myhost.com'>home</a></li>
  <li><a href='http://myhost.com/page1'>page 1</a></li>
  <li><a href='/page 2'>page 2</a></li>
  <li><a href='http://myhost.com/page 3'>page 3</a></li>
  <li><a href='http://myhost.com/page%204'>page 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="test.html">test</a></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#menu a").click(function(){
            var browserUrl = window.location.href;
            var myUrl = $(this).attr('href');
            alert(browserUrl);
            alert(myUrl);
            if(browserUrl === myUrl ){
                $(this).parent().addClass('active');
            }

        return false; // to prevent the default behavior of the a tag when clicked
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```